# phpunit says I have double definitions of class

Tags: php, phpunit

I have several tests files, one file that others will inherit from.

this is the parent file:

```
<?php

namespace Initial\Reports\Tests;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Initial\Reports\DataFetcher;

const DONT_CARE = true;

class ReportTest extends \TestCase {

}
```

and all other tests inherit from the above file

they all sit on same folder.

and when I run

```
phpunit path/to/folder/
```

I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Initial\Reports\Tests\ReportTest in /Users/tzookb/Sites/lps.core/app/initial/Reports/tests/ReportTest.php
```

Comment: Somewhere in your `path/to/folder` or `Initial\Reports\Tests` namespace must be another class named `ReportTest`. Rename one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the naming of my tests parent:

```
ReportTest
```

so phpunit reads it as another test class.

I changed it to

```
ReportTestCase
```

and than phpunit didn't find it as a test, and all worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing more than one `include` of the file containing your class. An `include` causes PHP to act as though the contents of the included file were simply typed where the `include` statement is. Do it more than once, and you'll have two definitions of your class.

You should be using (1) [an autoloader function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) (see [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)) or (2) using `require` instead of `include`.

The other possibility, of course, is that you really do have two definitions of the class, in which case you need to rename one.